# where is the: FXML Specification?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I am looking for the Oracle **FXML specification**, reference manual or just user guide. I've come across quite a few books and blogs using the literal name, and nothing on Google, Stackoverflow, Wikipdeia or the JavaFX pages to link with such a document.  The nearest I've come is a kind of help page:

- [Introduction to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html)

A similar stackoverflow question:

- [FXML full reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715700/fxml-full-reference)

Has a few votes because the links are helpful so I'm not repeating them.  The main reference cited is the [**JavaFX API JavaDoc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/) which is decidedly not what I'm looking for because working off the JavaFX classes is only an talk about a tag as an object.

I'm seeking the FXML specification for what's tags mean, what are the combination rules, etc.  Not just what's implemented in the classes a tag may model.  I also feel that if there's books and blogs and conference papers out there with the term, "FXML Specification" in them, such a document ought to exit.  *Not so*?

Comment: Not so.  There is no specification.

Comment: @will what you were looking specification for? I'm planning to make open source FXML parser, as I don't like vanilla FXMLLoader and want BiDirrectional binding :)

Comment: That's a very good idea.  I reckon the best place to being is the Gluon Scene Builder open source project.  There's no schema (XSD) with the fxml so it is all about the JavaFx entity class-es as far as I can tell. _afaik_ the JavaFx parser will be Open Source so you can probably fork it.  FXML itself permits arbitrary components classes to be loaded as FXML entities ... But parser tools like SceneBuilder aren't able to deal with that aspect of the language.  Swing has a similar problem, but at least it can load the components in the designer.  I would like to get in the loop when you start.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, but those two links are the best you can get.

The [Introduction to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) describes (somewhat badly) what is possible in FXML and what special tags can be used.

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/) lists which elements can be used and what properties they can have.

There is no other specification for FXML.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  People at lease can know that these Google hits are mis-spoken:  ["FXML Specification"](http://www.google.com.au/search?q="FXML+Specification").  Best to leave the question Open, for the time when [**Oracle**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) get of their posterior and write one.

Comment: One errata or caveat; it looks like many people call the FXML source file: a FXML Specification.  Not to be confused with "_actual_ documentation"