# Does JavaFX FXML support XInclude?

Tags: xml, javafx, fxml, xinclude

Does JavaFX FXML support XInclude? (http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude)

Since there does not seem to be a formal FXML Specification ([where is the: FXML Specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008723/where-is-the-fxml-specification))

I am asking here.

It also seems that the XML parser in use must have namespace enabled. ([Default support for xinclude in Java 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581939/default-support-for-xinclude-in-java-6?rq=1))

Answer (score 0):

While FXML does not support Xinclude, it does have its own implementation of the functionality.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements